# SAN Performance

Tags: performance, san

Have a question regarding SAN performance specifically EMC VNX SAN.  I have a significant number of processes spread over number of blade servers running concurrently.  The number of processes is typically around 200.  Each process loads 2 small files from storage, one 3KB one 30KB.  There are millions (20) of files to be processed.  The processes are running on Windows Server on VMWare.  The way this was originally setup was 1TB LUNs on the SAN bundled into a single 15TB drive in VMWare and then shared as a network share from one Windows instance to all the processes.  The processes running concurrently and the performance is abysmal.  Essentially, 200 simultaneous requests are being serviced by the SAN through Windows share at the same time and the SAN is not handling it too well.  I'm looking for suggestions to improve performance.

Answer (score 4):

With all performance questions, there's a degree of 'it depends'.

When you're talking about accessing a SAN, there's a chain of potential bottlenecks to unravel. First though, we need to understand what the actual problem is:

- Do we have problems with throughput - e.g. sustained transfer, or latency?
- It sounds like we're looking at random read IO - which is one of the hardest workloads to service, because predictive caching doesn't work.

So begin at the beginning:

- What sort of underlying storage are you using?

  Have you fallen into the trap of buying big SATA, configuring it RAID-6? I've seen plenty of places do this because it looks like cheap terabytes, without really doing the sums on the performance. A SATA drive starts to slow down at about 75 IO operations per second. If you've got big drives - 3TB for example - that's 25 IOPs per terabytes. As a rough rule of thumb, 200 per drive for FC/SAS and 1500 for SSD.
- are you tiering?
  Storage tiering is a clever trick of making a 'sandwich' out of different speeds of disk. This usually works, because *usually* only a small fraction of a filesystem is 'hot' - so you can put the hot part on fast disk, and the cold part on slow disk, and average performance looks better. This doesn't work for random IO or cold read accesses. Nor does it work for full disk transfers - as only 10% of it (or whatever proportion) can ever be 'fast' and everything else has to go the slow way.
- What's your array level contention? 
  The point of SAN is that you aggregate your performance, such that each user has a higher peak and a lower average, as this reflects *most* workloads. (When you're working on a document, you need a burst of performance to fetch it, but then barely any until you save it again).
- How are you accessing your array? 
  Typically SAN is accessed using a Fiber Channel network. There's a whole bunch of technical differences with 'real' networks, but they don't matter to you - but contention and bandwidth still do. With ESX in particular, I find there's a tendency to underestimate storage IO needs. (Multiple VMs using a single pair of HBAs means you get contention on the ESX server).
- what sort of workload are we dealing with? 
  One of the other core advantages of storage arrays is caching mechanisms. They generally have very large caches and some clever algorithms to take advantage of workload patterns such as temporal locality and sequential or semi-sequential IO. Write loads are easier to handle for an array, because despite the horrible write penalty of RAID-6, write operations are under a soft time constraint (they can be queued in cache) but read operations are under a hard time constraint (the read cannot complete until the block is fetched). 
  This means that for true random read, you're basically not able to cache at all, which means you get worst case performance.
- Is the problem *definitely* your array? Sounds like you've a single VM with 15TB presented, and that VM is handling the IO. That's a bottleneck right there. How many IOPs are the VM generating to the ESX server, and what's the contention like there? What's the networking like? How many other VMs are using the same ESX server and might be sources of contention? Is it a pass through LUN, or VMFS datastore with a VMDK?

So - there's a bunch of potential problems, and as such it's hard to roll it back to a single source. All I can give you is some general recommendations to getting good IO performance.

- fast disks (they're expensive, but if you need the IO, you need to spend money on it).
- Shortest path to storage (don't put a VM in the middle if you can possibly avoid it. For CIFS shares a NAS head may be the best approach).
- Try to make your workload cacheable - I know, easier said than done. But with millions of files, if you've got a predictable fetch pattern your array will start prefetching, and it'll got a LOT faster. You may find if you start archiving the files into large 'chunks' you'll gain performance (because the array/client will fetch the whole chunk, and it'll be available for the next client).

Basically the 'lots of small random IO operations' especially on slow disks is really the worst case for storage, because none of the clever tricks for optimization work.